# UIWebView swift change links color

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I get HTML from server and place it in UIWebView with loadHTMLString(string,url). HTML can be different at runtime. Also it can contain a video - it is a reason why I can't use UITextView or UILabel with attributedText.

I get HTML from server and it means that all colors and attributes defined before, and I can not edit it dynamically because, how i said, HTML can be different at runtime.

I tried to use

```
webView.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

But it not helped. Are there ways to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have predefined colors for a category of links, you can change the color attribute of those links, before your UIWebview loads that html content.
UIWebview delegate methods can be used to check the html content before its loaded